# Continue stream after subscribe

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have two streams, that looks as follow:

```
const source1 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .map(() => "I am source 1")
  .do((x) => console.log(x));
const sub1 = source1.subscribe((v) => console.log("Subscribe 2"));

const source2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
   .do(() => console.log("execute!"))
   .switchMapTo(source1)
   .do(() => console.log("After switch map."))
   .map((x) => "source2");

source2.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Without click on document I've got following output:

```
"I am source 1"
"Subscribe 2"
```

Further clicks the output is:

```
"execute!"
"I am source 1"
"After switch map."
"source2"
```

How can I force the stream `source1` to subscribe by further clicks and after continue with stream `source2`?

I am expecting after several clicks following output:

```
"I am source 1"
"Subscribe 2"
"execute!"
"I am source 1"
"After switch map."
"source2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables can be thought of as functions. And subscribing is like calling a function.

i.e

```js
const o = Rx.Observable.of(1);
o.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

is very similar to

```js
const f = () => 1;
console.log ( f() );
```

Just like calling a function doesn't modify the function. Subscribing to an Observable doesn't modify the observable. The subscription isn't *attached* to the Observable in any way. It's the returned subscription which is holding any state.

---

The two calls to subscribe in your example are completely independant and is the same as this:

```js
const source1 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .map(() => "I am source 1")
  .do((x) => console.log(x));
const sub1 = source1.subscribe((v) => console.log("Subscribe 2"));

const source1_v2 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .map(() => "I am the same as source 1")
  .do((x) => console.log(x));

const source2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click')
   .do(() => console.log("execute!"))
   .switchMapTo(source1_v2)
   .do(() => console.log("After switch map."))
   .map((x) => "source2");

source2.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```